# Add VPN type to Network configurations

Tags: release-juno, networking, vpn

I'm trying to save a OpenConnect vpn in the network settings, however i'm only prompted with two types (OpenVPN and Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol PPTP) even 'tough i've installed OpenConnect and connected from the terminal many times.

[image: OpenVPN and Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol PPTP options]

How can I add the option in the Network Manager so I can save this VPN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the openconnect packages:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

followed by:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

The `Choose a VPN Connection Type` dropdown will now contain two new entries:

- Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN (openconnect)
- Juniper Network Connect (openconnect)

  [image: VPN drop-down extra]

A reboot might be necessary instead of the network-manager restart.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick